# Checking all letters appear at least once in String

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm using this regex to check that every letter appears at least once:

```
String regex = "(?i)(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)(?=.*f)(?=.*g)(?=.*h)(?=.*i)(?=.*j)(?=.*k)(?=.*l)(?=.*m)(?=.*n)(?=.*o)(?=.*p)(?=.*q)(?=.*r)(?=.*s)(?=.*t)(?=.*u)(?=.*v)(?=.*w)(?=.*x)(?=.*y)(?=.*z).*
"
```

Example:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

contains all the english letters but my regex is not working.

What I'm doing wrong, or is there any other way to check for [pangrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram).

Comment: what do you mean by not working? it is working here https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/10 .... IMO you should add anchors `^$` too

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jfstRdr3 @vks, still incorrect match.

Comment: ` 

    (?i)^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)(?=.*f)(?=.*g)(?=.*h)(?=.*i)(?=.*j)(?=.*k)(?=.*l)(?=.*m)(?=.*n)(?=.*o)(?=.*p)(?=.*q)(?=.*r)(?=.*s)(?=.*t)(?=.*u)(?=.*v)(?=.*w)(?=.*x)(?=.*y)(?=.*z).*$

` it should be this

Comment: It's also working here http://fiddle.re/5ydx46 with the `regex` you posted in your question

Comment: thank you, it's working. @vks

Comment: @whiteFang added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    (?i)^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)(?=.*f)(?=.*g)(?=.*h)(?=.*i)(?=.*j)(?=.*‌​k)(?=.*l)(?=.*m)(?=.*n)(?=.*o)(?=.*p)(?=.*q)(?=.*r)(?=.*s)(?=.*t)(?=.*u)(?=.*v)(?‌​=.*w)(?=.*x)(?=.*y)(?=.*z).*$
```

Add `anchors` `^$` to make a strict match instead of partial matches.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/11

Answer (score 2):

There is a significantly simpler and faster way than regular expressions to check that a string is a pangram.

In small steps,

- Convert the string to lowercase
- Reduce it to unique letters
- Sort it
- Does it equal `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`?